# Проблема сокрытия пароля звездочками

Tags: c, вывод, пароль, password

написал код, который считывает пароль и выводит его при нажатии Enter. Предусмотрен Backspace

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void){
    SetConsoleCP (1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP (1251);
    char password[100],c;
    int i;
    i=0;
    while ((password[i]=getch())!='\r'){
        if (password[i]=='\b' && i!=0){
            printf("%s", "\b \b");
            i--;
            continue;
        }
        printf("%c", '*');
        i++;
    }
    printf("\npassword is %s\n", password);
return 0;
}
```

Вопрос в выводе.

```
Вывод при пароле "qwe"(звездочки это еще ввод самого пароля)
***
\
 r╗Мюad is qwe
```

.

```
Вывод при пароле qwerty
******
╗Мюaword is qwerty
```

.

```
Вывод при пароле qwertyuiop
**********
password is qwertyuiop
```

Используя или нет Backspace, вывод не меняется. Можете подсказать, что не так?

Comment: Кажется, нулевой байт в конце строки `password` забыли поставить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фокус в том что ты по этому условию (password[i]=getch())!='\r') сохранишь последним символом /r - то есть возврат каретки и перезатрешь какую-то часть слова password, а когда символов больше возрат каретки происходит позже

```
while ((password[i]=getch())!='\r'){
        if (password[i]=='\b' && i!=0){
            printf("%s", "\b \b");
            i--;
            continue;
        }
        printf("%c", '*');
        i++;
    }
    password[i] = '\0';
    printf("\npassword is %s\n", password);
```

- твоя панацея

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял, что к чему)